# Should I upgrade my Moto G4 to Nougat?

Tags: updates, motorola-moto-g, 7.0-nougat

I my personal phone is a Moto G4 (2GB RAM, 16GB storage). I have bought it mainly to learn how to develop apps for Android (currently, marshmallow is working very well for me).

I've seen that my phone has an upgrade ready to download - the new Android 7.0 (today, he is 6.0.1, Marshmallow). I usually don't upgrade to newer versions unless I'm sure my cell won't be slower/somehow damaged by it. So I would like your advice, specifically to my phone.

- Will it run ok with my 2GB of memory? (today, my phone is really fast, I don't want it to become one of those phones that makes simple tasks, like reading whatsapp/SMS slow).
- Will it use more storage space than Marshmallow? How much it will use, approximately?
- Is there any known problem (incompatibility, apps that stopped running, unusable phone resources)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Official updates are usually alright on those aspects. Also, if you're learning to dev, staying on the cutting edge and using new APIs are quite important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just upgraded my Moto G4. Here are my impressions:

- The systems are pretty similar, no big difference.
- Nougat seems a little bit faster than marshmallow (might be due to some apps I was always keeping in background, which were closed during the upgrade)
- No data loss (at least didn't notice anything until now)
- I had to reconfigure my dual-sim call/sms selection (it has apparently changed - more options - on 7.0, but I could configure with the same settings I had before, which were working for me).

Summarizing, I am happy with the upgrade :)